# how to use data type as "blob" during migration in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I want to store HTML in the database as blob data type when I try to migrate getting errors

```
Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('project_name');
            $table->blob('project_description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

```
php artisan module:migrate projects
Migrating: 2019_10_17_125423_create_projects_table
```

> BadMethodCallException  : Method
>   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::blob does not exist.
>
> at
>   xampp\htdocs\minidmsapi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable.php:104

Comment: you can use this `$table->binary('name');` it is equivalent to `blob`

Comment: @SalmanZafar yeah its working

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In `Laravel` they have `binary` instead of `blob`. `binary` is equivalent to `blob`.

You can use it like:

```
$table->binary('name');
```

For more information see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#columns).

Thanks